# i am not getting height which i am giving to it

Tags: html, css

hi guys i have given content to 80%height but i am not getting it please tell the mistake i have made .i have done webpages earlier in this similar way but this time only i am getting the error.i would be happy if anyone helps me out.

```css
body
{
 
 margin:0px;
 background-color:lightseagreen;
}

#wrapper
{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}
#header
{
height:10%;
width:100%; 
 
}
#navbar
{
height:10%;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
color:white;
float:left;
}
#navbar ul li
{
width:70%;
display:inline;
padding:17px 25px;
}
#navbar ul li a
{
color:white;    
    
}
#navbar ul li:hover
{
background-color:lightgrey;
}
#content
{
width:100%;
height:80%;
background-color:red;
float:left;
}
.details
{
width:100%;
height:80%;
float:left; 
 
}
#footer
{
width:100%;
height:10%;
background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>student</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ab.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!--start wrapper-->
<div id="header">
<div id="navbar"><!--start nav-->
<ul>
<li>About us</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Services</li>
<li>Sign</li>
</ul>
</div><!--end nav-->
</div>
<div id="content"><!--start content-->
<div class="details">

here
</div> 
</div><!--end content-->
<div id="footer"><!--start footer-->
copyrights to N.sudharsan
</div><!--end footer-->
</div><!--end wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Percentage will not work on the height for the outer div (wrapper). Add height in PX

Comment: My code will work for you bro. Have a check of it . Since PX will work fine and i got the output too.

Answer (score 1):

> Apply this CSS Style for you content div:

```
#content
{
width:100%;
min-height:450px;
background-color:red;
float:left;
}
```

It will fix your problem

Comment: ty its slightly changed but y the percentage is not been taken and it takes pixel value

Comment: @sudharsan Have a check here. Here is a clear explanation about it. We have to specify height in % and min-height in px. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-height/

Comment: height is the constant which will take it up only if it has the following % and min-height is that it will take up the height specified and after that it will not extend.

Comment: Hope so your required output for the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
html{height:100%;} body{min-height:100%}
```

Your Other code should same.

Answer (score 0):

it just means the height is 80% of your height in #wrapper
so set a size in your wrapper.

```
body
 {

margin:0px;
background-color:lightseagreen;
}

 #wrapper
 {

  height:700px; min-height:100%; width:100%; background-color:red; padding:0px; margin:0px;

 }
 #header { height:10%; width:100%;       }
 #navbar { height:10%; width:100%; background-color:black; color:white;     float:left; }
 #navbar ul li {

       width:70%;
       display:inline;
       padding:17px 25px;
       }
       #navbar ul li a
       {
       color:white;    

        }
        #navbar ul li:hover
        {
        background-color:lightgrey;
        }
        #content
        {
        margin-top:5%;
        width:100%;
        height:80%;
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        }
        .details
        {
        width:100%;
        height:80%;
        float:left; 

        }
        #footer
        {
        float:left;
        margin-top:100%;
        width:100%;
        height:10%;
        background-color:gray;
        }

        </style>
```